# Rails - n+1 queries even though association is preloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a Person class that has many Book(s), and each Book has one Bookmark.
In my code I'm doing something like this:

```
items = author.books.includes(:bookmark)
items.each { |item| generate_hash(item) }

def generate_hash(item)
  { ... rest ..., finished: item.try(:finished?) }
end
```

```
class Book
  def finished?
    bookmark ? bookmark.page == self.pages : false
  end
end
```

Using `item.try(:finished?)` triggers a select query to get each individual bookmark even though I've preloaded them. However, if I change it to `finished: item.is_a?(Book) ? item.finished? : nil` it triggers only one query to get all the bookmarks just as I planned. Can anyone make sense of this?

EDIT - adding the queries I'm getting in the log:

```
with item.try(:finished?):
Bookmark Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  `bookmarks`.* FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `bookmarks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `bookmarks`.`book_id` = 41 LIMIT 1
Bookmark Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  `bookmarks`.* FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `bookmarks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `bookmarks`.`book_id` = 42 LIMIT 1
Bookmark Load (3.9ms)  SELECT  `bookmarks`.* FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `bookmarks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `bookmarks`.`book_id` = 43 LIMIT 1
Bookmark Load (3.3ms)  SELECT  `bookmarks`.* FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `bookmarks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `bookmarks`.`book_id` = 44 LIMIT 1
```

```
# with item.is_a?(Book) ? item.finished? : nil
Bookmark Load (2.6ms)  SELECT `bookmarks`.* FROM `bookmarks` WHERE `bookmarks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `bookmarks`.`book_id` IN (41, 42, 43, 44)
```

Comment: Why do you need `try` / `is_a?(Book)` in the first place? From your code it seems that each `item` must be an instance of `Book`. Maybe you’re feeding non-book items to your method somewhere else?

Comment: You're preloading `books => bookmark` but then querying `bookmark.page` .. don't you want to preload pages `books => bookmark => page` in that case?

Comment: This is just an example out of my head, I know the logic is not good, however, it does resemble the problem I currently have. @Stefan

Comment: @maxpleaner ^^^

Comment: Question: do you do this in the console and can you see `/* loading for inspect */` after the query? Rails has recently made some changes that it forces reloading of the association on inspect call. This comment might appear after the SQL query for books

Comment: @BroiSatse I've edited the post with a similar data I see in the log, however, I didn't notice any comments like the one you mentioned.

Comment: can you show the queries?

Comment: _"This is just an example out of my head"_ – you have to either post your _actual_ code or a [mcve]. Otherwise the code won’t reflect your SQL queries and vice-versa.

Comment: @Stefan I can't post the actual code since then I would violate the NDA. However, the models and methods I posted are almost identical in their behavior, so rather than focusing on the logic of the code, I would prefer to understand what causes the problem I mentioned.

Comment: **could not reproduce** in normal cases. i guess the list `items` you query and the `items` you use to `generate_hash` are different, there's something else in the list which also responds to `bookmark` but they are not in the first `items` you query (which call `includes`), so if you call `is_a?(Book)` you filter all items on the first query so of course their's bookmarks are already preloaded, otherwise you also call `bookmark` on those items which didn't preload bookmarks.

Comment: @LamPhan, so if 'items' is an array (and not a relation object) that contains books and other models, can that cause the problem?

Comment: of course, array of books (model, not relation) which you fetched with `includes` will be set preloaded bookmarks but other models will not (even other model is a Book, but not books be fetched with preloaded bookmarks), then if other models could respond to bookmark (or another Book which not includes bookmarks) will trigger query (since other_model.bookmark has not been preloaded yet). you should verify that again on your code.